# code coverage in python using coverage.py

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py, python-coverage

I am trying to understand running coverage for python scripts. I am not able to understand a scenario where i try to run coverage for a simple script which has an infinite loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "The only statement!!!"

while True:
    pass
```

After invoking coverage for this script, I will kill this process, since it is an infinite loop and if i try to get the result I am getting like:

1. coverage run sample.py
2. kill sample
3. coverage report -m

`Name    Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------`

I am not getting any coverage report. Am i doing some thing which is fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Can you include the console output from the steps above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`coverage` needs to be able to write its data out at program end, and if it can't handle the exit signal then it will not generate a report.

So it depends how you are killing your process and how `coverage` handles the signal - works fine for me when using Ctrl+C (i.e. sending SIGINT) to interrupt `sample.py`

```
$ coverage run sample.py
The only statement!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 5, in <module>
    while True:
KeyboardInterrupt

$ coverage report -m
Name     Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------
sample       3      0   100%
```

If you are using the `kill` utility with no options then you are sending SIGTERM by default, try `kill -INT <pid>` instead.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now i have a different problem. Coverage.py's documentation says, it doesnt work well with thread module. So is there any other coverage tool for python that supports thread also?

Comment: I don't know about other coverage tools, but [this documentation page](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/trouble.html) for Coverage.py says it will work fine if you use the [higher-level threading interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). So you could wrap your thread functions with thread classes.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Also i found that to get coverage results you should use sys.exit on all threads.